# Orchard and Visual Studio 2012 command line error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, command-line, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I'm trying to create a new theme in orchard command line but i get an error.
Thank you in advance.

orchard> codegen theme CWSTheme

### Error executing command "codegen theme CWSTheme"

```
None of the constructors found with 'Orchard.Environment.AutofacUtil.DynamicProx
y2.ConstructorFinderWrapper' on type 'Orchard.Security.Authorizer' can be invoke
d with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'Orchard.Security.IAuthorizationService authorizationSe
rvice' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Orchard.Security.IAuthorizationService, Orchar
d.UI.Notify.INotifier, Orchard.IWorkContextAccessor)'.

Exception Details: Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the const
ructors found with 'Orchard.Environment.AutofacUtil.DynamicProxy2.ConstructorFin
derWrapper' on type 'Orchard.Security.Authorizer' can be invoked with the availa
ble services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'Orchard.Security.IAuthorizationService authorizationSe
rvice' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Orchard.Security.IAuthorizationService, Orchar
d.UI.Notify.INotifier, Orchard.IWorkContextAccessor)'.
```

Comment: Does your project build? Have you got the Orchard source copy?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

- Exit the Orchard Command Line
- If you can stop site running on your webserver
- In App_Data delete the contents of the dependencies folder (these will get regenerated)
- Try the command line again and hopefully all is fixed
- If you need to restart the site

I find this often clears up a lot of errors and is the Orchard equivalent of turning it off and on again.